# Help to parse the JSON

Tags: json-ld

The below code is working perfectly. Need help to parse the JSON with if ... else logic based on item[0] for different DIV like Lessons, Videos, etc.

```
<script>
fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzz76WS63UCCo9ZripiLrS4Nf3iGsBMS_D7VU8wI9y7lI0ZhJvvXREtmnnpjWfAv23Lvw/exec')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        let lessons = data.content.reduce((prev1, item1) => {
            if (item1[0] === "Lessons") {
                return prev1 + `<div class="col">
                                 <div class="card h-100">
                                    <img src="#" class="card-img-top img-responsive" alt="...">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">${item1[0]}</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">${item1[1]}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href=${item1[16]} class="btn btn-primary stretched-link" target="blank">Read</a>
                                 </div>
                               </div>`;
            } else {
                return prev1;
            }
        }, "");
        document.querySelector("#Lessons").innerHTML = lessons;
        let videos = data.content.reduce((prev2, item2) => {
            if (item2[0] === "Videos") {
                return prev2 + `<div class="col">
                                 <div class="card h-100">
                                    <img src="#" class="card-img-top img-responsive" alt="...">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">${item2[0]}</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">${item2[1]}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href=${item2[16]} class="btn btn-primary stretched-link" target="blank">Play Video</a>
                                 </div>
                               </div>`;
            } else {
                return prev2;
            }
        }, "");
        document.querySelector("#Videos").innerHTML = videos;
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Questions specific to [coding/programming](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here. You might be able to ask this over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).